# Why v.surf.idw returns only two value (one is nan)

Tags: qgis, dem, inverse-distance-weighted

I am trying to perform a vector interpolation of a point shapefile with the intent of eventually creating a DEM. No matter what I try, I get only 2 values one of them is NAN, and nothing is working to fix it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just found that the data in the geographic coordinate system. Should run this function after reproject. 
as request: interpolation algorithm doesn't deal with the geographic coordinate which caused the error